# Como redireccionar con un modal

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-5

Cuando el usuario presiona el botón de registrar, le aparecerá un mensaje de validación correcta, pero debido al RedirectToAction hace que no se visualice el mensaje. Ese mensaje de validación es un modal personalizado, y quisiera saber si hay una manera de que cuando el usuario cierre ese modal ME REDIRECCIONE A LA PAGINA QUE YO QUIERA.

**Controlador**

```
public ActionResult CrearCliente()
    {
        return View(new ClsCliente());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CrearCliente(ClsCliente cliente)
    {

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ViewBag.mensaje = "error";
            return View(cliente);
        }

        string mensaje = "";

        try
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into tb_clientes values(@id,@nombre,@direc,@idpais,@fono)", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", cliente.idcliente);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nombre", cliente.nommbrecia);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@direc", cliente.direccion);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idpais", cliente.idpais);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fono", cliente.telefono);
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            mensaje = "exito";
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            mensaje = ex.Message;
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }

        ViewBag.mensaje = mensaje;



        return RedirectToAction("MostrarClientes");
    }
```

**Vista**

```
    @model FormularioCharlas.Models.ClsCliente

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "CrearCliente";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>CrearCliente</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>ClsCliente</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.idcliente, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.idcliente, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.idcliente, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.nommbrecia, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.nommbrecia, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.nommbrecia, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.direccion, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.direccion, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.direccion, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.idpais, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.idpais, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.idpais, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.telefono, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.telefono, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.telefono, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" id="id_cliente" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    //===============SWEET ALERT===============

    var msg = "@ViewBag.mensaje";

    if (msg != "") {
        if (msg == "exito") {
            Swal.fire(
                'Registro Exitoso!',
                'Se agrego una nueva charla!',
                'success'
            );

            //alert(msg);
        } else {
            Swal.fire(
                'Ocurrio un error!',
                'No se pudo registrar su nueva charla, asegúrese de completar todo el formulario, si el problema continua comuníquese con el área de informática!',
                'error'
            );
        }
    }
</script>
```

**Imagen**

Así es mi modal:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por qué estas usando el redirect? Por qué no simplemente cargar la vista? Te vuelvo a preguntar acá, cuál es el flujo de tu funcionalidad?

Comment: Creo que voy entendiendo un poco. Lo que quieres es guardar los datos, mostrar el modal, y redireccionar a tu lista general. Estoy en lo correcto?

Comment: Así es amigo @KodiakMx

Comment: Como lo implemento?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu problema principal está en que quieres realizar dos acciones en una sola llamada. La forma más sencilla de realizar lo que quieres es separando las acciones.

Primero necesitas indicar en tu controlador que al hacer el post, solo regrese a la vista con el modelo que recibiste y tu mensaje en el ViewBag:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CrearCliente(ClsCliente cliente)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        ViewBag.mensaje = "error";
        return View(cliente);
    }

    string mensaje = "";

    try
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into tb_clientes values(@id,@nombre,@direc,@idpais,@fono)", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", cliente.idcliente);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nombre", cliente.nommbrecia);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@direc", cliente.direccion);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idpais", cliente.idpais);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fono", cliente.telefono);
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        mensaje = "exito";
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        mensaje = ex.Message;
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }

    ViewBag.mensaje = mensaje;

    return View(Cliente);
}
```

Eso cargará tu vista con los datos de la forma, y como tienes algo en el ViewBag.mensaje, te mostrará tu modal.

Ahora, lo que necesitas hacer en tu vista para que te redireccione a tu lista, es con javascript (usualmente jquery que imagino será un concepto nuevo para ti que necesitaras entender) es hacer la redirección. Yo pondría algo así sencillo como:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#id_de_tu_boton_del_modal').on('click', function () {
            $(location).attr('href','@Url.Action("MostrarClientes")');
        });
    });
</script>
```

--- Editado

Después de verificar la documentación de la librería del modal que estas usando, lo que puedes hacer en lugar del código jquery que te mencionaba, puedes agregar una propiedad más a tu modal justo así:

```
Swal.fire(
{
    title: 'Registro Exitoso!',
    text: 'Se agrego una nueva charla!',
    type: 'success',
    onClose: () => {
        window.location = '/tu_controlador/MostrarClientes';
    }
});
```

Comment: Amigo @KodiakMx, no me llega direcciona, intente con esto pero aun así no tuve resultados.

$(document).on('click', '.swal2-confirm' ,function () {
            $(location).attr('href','@Url.Action("MostrarClientes")');
        });

Comment: @GianFrancoAlexisPomaVidal checa la edición que acabo de hacer.

Comment: Le agregue con Jquery y funciono a la perfección ;)
onClose: () => {
                            $(location).attr('href','@Url.Action("MostrarClientes")')
                        }

Comment: Gracias por tomarte el tiempo de ayudarme amigo @KodiakMx, espero que puedas seguirme ayudando en caso tenga más dudas.

Comment: Ya que estas usando el SweetAlert2, te recomiendo seas consistente y utilices la segunda opción que te ponía.. pero es solo recomendación.. Lo bueno es que ya pudiste..

Comment: Tomaré tu recomendación :D